# If $R/\mathfrak{a}$ is flat, then $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

**Problem**: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal such that $R/\mathfrak{a}$ is flat. Then $\mathfrak{a}^2=\mathfrak{a}$.

**My attempt**: $R/\mathfrak{a}$ is flat iff $\alpha\otimes (R/\mathfrak{a})\hookrightarrow R/\mathfrak{a}$ is an injection induced by the inclusion $\mathfrak{a}\hookrightarrow R$. I know that $\mathfrak{a}\otimes (R/\mathfrak{a})=\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2$. Therefore, if I show that the first injection maps to $0$, then $\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2=0$ and so $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}^2$.

So, given $x\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $r\in R/\mathfrak{a}$, how do I get to $x\otimes r=0$? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can say R/a is flat only if tensoring with a is injective. But it implies this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\otimes \bar r\in\mathfrak a\otimes (R/\mathfrak a)$. This gets mapped to $a\otimes \bar r\in R\otimes(R/\mathfrak a)$. In $R\otimes(R/\mathfrak a)$, we have
$$a\otimes \bar r=1\otimes a\bar r=1\otimes 0=0.$$

Comment: Why do we have, in $R\otimes (R/\alpha)$, $a\otimes \bar r=1\otimes a\bar r$?

Comment: We are taking tensor product over $R$. So $a\in R$ can act as a *scalar* and hence we can write it on either side of the tensor symbol. (Why can't we do it in $\mathfrak a\otimes (R/\mathfrak a)$?)

Comment: In general, in $M\otimes_R N$, we have $$(rm)\otimes n=m\otimes (rn).$$